# Append object to a existing file in android

Tags: java, android

i have append an object to a existing file but i can not read it ,i can read the first object and this is  my code 
What is the problem ??

```
try{

       FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("f.txt",MODE_PRIVATE | MODE_APPEND );

       ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
       String a=new String ("Hello  object1 ");
       String b=new String("Hello  object2 ");
       String c=new String("Hello  object3 ");

       oos.writeObject(a);
       oos.writeObject(b);
       oos.writeObject(c);
       oos.close();

       // Reading it back..

       FileInputStream fis = openFileInput("f.txt");

       ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

       //ois=new ObjectInputStream(fis);
       //  r=(String)ois.readObject(); 
              String r;
       while ((r= (String)ois.readObject()) != null) {
          Log.i("while Read r",r);

          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),r, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }

       ois.close();

       }catch (Exception e){
           Log.i("Exception",e.getMessage());
       }
```

I hope you can help me!! thanks.

Comment: are you receiving an error, or is it just not reading more than one object?

Comment: i am sorry ?? i can just read the three above object and i receive an error, also if i add a fourth object i can not read it

Comment: what error are you receiving?

Comment: 05-02 22:56:26.852: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4714): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{moh.com/moh.com.storge}: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
 05-02 22:56:26.852: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4714):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1622)

Comment: look john in the first run to the above code i can read all the objects i saved then the program crash ,if i run it again and save a new object i can not read the last object i saved in the second run. i am sorry if i confused you

Comment: nullpointerexception at a println statement, but I don't see any println lines in this file.  Are you sure your error is coming from this try/catch block?  Or, are you sure that the error you posted has to do with this code?

Comment: OK ,forget about the exception .if i run the same code again and append a new objects , i can not read it and i have the following message  exception from e.getMessage():                                                  05-02 23:34:53.522: INFO/Exception(6168): Wrong format: ac
the second message   e.getStackTrace().toString():05-02 23:34:53.612: ERROR/Exc(6168): [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@40528f00

Answer (score 1):

The code seems correct just some modification in "While" , Check below:

```
try{

   FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("f.txt",MODE_PRIVATE | MODE_APPEND );

   ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
   String a=new String ("Hello  object1 ");
   String b=new String("Hello  object2 ");
   String c=new String("Hello  object3 ");

   oos.writeObject(a);
   oos.writeObject(b);
   oos.writeObject(c);
   oos.close();

   // Reading it back..

   FileInputStream fis = openFileInput("f.txt");

   ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

   //ois=new ObjectInputStream(fis);
   //  r=(String)ois.readObject(); 
          String r;
   while (fis.available() > 0) {
      r= (String)ois.readObject();
      Log.i("while Read r",r);

      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),r, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }

   ois.close();

   }catch (Exception e){
       Log.i("Exception",e.getMessage());
   }
```